# display-table no working as intended - left,right columns

Tags: html, css

I want the left and right column to be the same height with a min-height of whole browswer-height.

**html:**

```
<div id="outfit-wrapper" class="clearfix">

    <div id="header"></div> 

    <div id="outfit-body">  
        <div class="table-row">            

            <div id="outfit-area" class="table-cell">      
                whatever content
                <div class="footer">
                 content within #outfit-area (bottom of #outfit-area)
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>                     
            </div>

            <!-- I WANT the green left column to be the same height as
            right blue column - how do I achieve this? -->

             <div id="products-area" class="table-cell">
                 here are some products. here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.here are some products.
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>        

        </div> <!--end table row -->
    </div> <!-- end outfit-body-->

</div> <!--end outfit-wrapper-->
```

**css:**

```
/* clearfix */
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden;display: block;font-size: 0;content: " ";clear: both;height: 0;}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
.clearfix { display: block; }

/* 100% height layout - header is 10% of this height, #outfit-area and #products-area 90% */
html,body {margin: 0;padding: 0;height:100%;}
body {background: #ffffff;font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; font-size:13px;}

#header {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    min-height:45px; /* Min-height is used because loogotype must be visible to user */
    background:yellow;
}


#outfit-body {
    display:table;   
}

.table-row {
    display:table-row;
}

.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#outfit-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:98%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding:0;
}

/* left column */
#outfit-area {
    position:absolute; /* I must have this here so 100% height can be achieved (because I have percentage height in parent div #outfit-wrapper */
    min-height:90%; /* header is 10% of the total height */
    width:60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
    border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:green;
}

#products-area {
    width:40%;
    height:90%; /* header is 10% of the total height */
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
    background-color:blue;
}

#outfit-area .footer {
    display:table-cell;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

Take a look at the jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TgM7t/24/

I want the left (green) column to be same height as blue (even when right column gets higher, then the green should be same height) I tried with display:table, table-cell, table-row stuff which I thought should work, but it's obviously something I am missing.

I know there are a lot of questions and answers on this subject, but I really can't find what I'm looking for...

**My question:** What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing the height in one of the table cells will cause the row height not to adjust accordingly. In your case, it is the `position: absolute;` and `min-height:90%;` lines in the css of`#outfit-area` that are causing the cell to expand beyond the row.

To achieve the design you are looking for (i.e. 10% header, 90% body), I would set the height on the container of the body to 90%. The table layout would guarantee that the children table-row and table-cell "divs" expand naturally and occupy all the space.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgM7t/39/).

The corresponding modifications in the css are:

```
#outfit-body {
    display:table;   
    height: 90%;
}
```

This already fixes the problem but I would also get rid of unnecessary height lines in the children (commented out below with "removed" mention):

```
#products-area {
    width:40%;
    /*height:90%;*/ /* header is 10% of the total height */ /*removed*/
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
    background-color:blue;
}

#outfit-area {
    /*position:absolute;*/ /*removed*/ /* I must have this here so 100% height can be achieved (because I have percentage height in parent div #outfit-wrapper */
    position: relative; /*added because outfit area contains children div*/
    /*min-height:90%;*/ /*removed*/ /* header is 10% of the total height */
    ......
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! The problem is that your demo does not work as I want either, because the .footer is not at the bottom of the left column (#outfit-area). I guess that is because the outfit-area does not have position:absolute with your solution? I tested to do a vertical-align:bottom with .footer-class but that didn't work either  (even if I got rid of position:absolute;bottom:0 for .footer)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Just add `position: relative;` to `#outfit-area`. See my edit (updated the demo as well).

Comment: @edisoufi - for some reason this doesn't seem to work in FF... Any idea? :-)

Comment: This article explains best how to divide a table-cell div vertically: [Rowspans & Colspans in CSS Tables](http://www.sitepoint.com/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/). It should set you on the right track. I am not going to update the answer as in your original post you only asked for the two columns having the same height, so maybe this is best left as additional info in comments... :)

Comment: thanks! I'll have a look at it! :-) I wish I could upvote you more :-)